# How to set null for generics in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

In my application I used **ViewBinding** for access to views and for this I create **Base Fragment** and write below codes. 
In **onDestroy** method I want null the views but show me error. 
My BaseFragment codes:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<T : ViewBinding>(private val bindingInflater: (inflater: LayoutInflater) -> T) : Fragment() {

    //Other
    var isNetworkAvailable = true

    private lateinit var viewBinding: T

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        viewBinding = bindingInflater(inflater)
        return viewBinding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        viewBinding = null
    }
}
```

Show me this error `Null can not be a value of a non-null type T` in this line `viewBinding = null` .

How can I fix it?

Comment: FYI You should be destroying your views and their bindings in `onDestroyView`. There's a subtle difference that manifests itself in case fragment enters detached state (for example: in view pager).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to declare nullable a type or a variable, you should use the `?`, right after your type declaration.

Following this [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-nullable-types)

```
val string : String = null  --> Nope, String is not nullable
val string : String? = null --> Yes, String is nullable
```

To assign a `null` value to a variable or a type you must declare it nullable.